# Excel "phantom" data: 600KB used by empty cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro-enabled Excel workbook that is ~1.5 MB in size. After progressively deleting sheets one by one, I found that ~600 KB was used in one specific sheet, even after all VBA, buttons, and visible data was cleared.

Specifically, if I delete rows 8-1200 via selecting the rows, right-click, "Delete", save, then 600 KB disappeared from the filesize. However, if I merely stripped formatting and cell contents/values from those same rows (select rows, set formatting options to Automatic, hit [Del] key, save), the 600 KB still remained.

What could be taking up the 600 KB?

Comment: try selecting them and click clear all. It is not about the information attached to the cell. It is about the information attached to a worksheet about its cells. Without clear all or deleting, the cells are still tagged as not being the default cells and so the worksheet stores information about them, their location etc. If you really want to see what is happening you can actually look at the worksheet file inside the workbook using a Zip tool. Unzip it (assuming an xlsx or xlsm) and open up the worksheet in a text editor. You can see the cell definitions.

Answer (score 1):

please check the following.. and may help

- number of sheets used (sheet1, sheet2.. etc)
- any equation formula may used during previous work
- formats of cells
- security cells or sheet..etc

thanks

Comment: I deleted all sheets but the 600KB sheet and deleted all VBA modules. Then, I reset formatting and cleared content for all cells in the one remaining sheet. Still 600KB+. Only deleting the actual (empty) rows got rid of the 600KB.